# Fetching list of data from Webpage

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to fetch list of companies from the url.

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

headers = {
        'Connection': 'keep-alive',
        'Cache-Control': 'max-age=0',
        'sec-ch-ua': '" Not;A Brand";v="99", "Google Chrome";v="91", "Chromium";v="91"',
        'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?0',
        'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': '1',
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.114 Safari/537.36',
        'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9',
        'Sec-Fetch-Site': 'cross-site',
        'Sec-Fetch-Mode': 'navigate',
        'Sec-Fetch-User': '?1',
        'Sec-Fetch-Dest': 'document',
        'Accept-Language': 'nl-NL,nl;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7',
    }

response = requests.get('https://www1.nseindia.com/products/content/derivatives/equities/fo_underlyinglist.htm', headers=headers)
df = pd.read_html(response.content)
option_companies = df[0][4:]
option_companies_list = option_companies["Symbol"].to_numpy()
option_companies_list = option_companies_list.tolist()
option_companies_list.pop()
print("option_companies_list : ", option_companies_list)
```

But, code is running but not printing the list. Please suggest if anything wrong is developed in the code.

Comment: Seems to work fine for me: `option_companies_list :  ['Derivatives on Individual Securities', 'AARTIIND', ...]`

Comment: @mozway: is it header issue? as I have upgraded to M1 chip?

Comment: Is there any other way of fetching the list?